# calling same method with passed values using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im trying to call a method passing different values to zip a folder , im using threads to process multiple runs of the same method ..

a listbox is populated with the pending jobs for processing and a system.timer is used to check the contents of the listbox every 30 seconds and process any jobs in the list ..

the process involves getting a record from the list .. which contains a zip filename , the zip file will be extracted on the current directory.

my problem is .. when I have more than 1 thread trying to unzip a file I only end up with 1 folder unzip  , for example .. the 1st call should unzip the folder1  , and the 2nd call should unzip the folder2  , however when the system.timer process the contents of the list .. I always get 1 unzipped folder .

The list will be populated with 2 entries everytime the program starts , if I place only folder1 entry on the list , the folder1 gets unzip , if I placed folder2 entry on the list , the folder2 gets unzip , so I know there are no problems with the entries.

heres a sample of my code :

```
private void JobStarterTimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        foreach (JobModel jm in ListofWaitingBackupJobs)
        {
            if (jm.Status.DataValue == "Waiting")
            {
                //check if the server has a pending job running ... 
                // add this check later
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartJob, jm);
            }
        }
 }


    private  void StartJob(object job)
    {

        string outputdirectory;
        outputdirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        ProcessStartInfo p2 = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p2.FileName = "7za.exe ";

        p2.Arguments = "x " + backupname + " -o" + @outputdirectory + " -y";


        p2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process x2 = Process.Start(p2);
        x2.WaitForExit();

    }
```

Comment: In your `StartJob` method you're *completely* ignoring the value of the `job` parameter. It's not clear what you want to do with it...

Comment: I would't use a listbox to keep track of jobs. Read something about work stealing job systems and implement it around a queue/stack using a synclock. Maybe all the jobs start the same process.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using the same output directory.  As Jon alluded to you may want to use the parameter to determine the relevant unique folder to unzip to.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake .. object job is cast into a Jobmodel ...
I solved this problem .. I declared backupname on top of the class ..so everytime I call the StartJob method ..it reads the latest backupname variable ..I should have declared backupname as a local variable inside the StartJob Method.